# Unable to populate 2nd select statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I have 2 select statement which the first select is populated by my first webservice request. User selects the desired data in the first select, in which will trigger the onChange method to retrieve first select object, run webservice again to retrieve another set of datas and populate the 2nd select statement.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-label">
  Select Kittens:
</div>
<select
ng-model ="options"
ng-options ="option.name for option in options"
ng-change="onChange(options)">
<option>--</option>
</select>   
<br>
 <div class="input-label">
  Select Age:
</div>  
<select
ng-options ="detail.age for detail in details">
<option>--</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
 .controller("ctrl",['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.options = [
          {id:1, name:'typeA'},
          {id:2, name:'typeB'},
          {id:3, name:'typeC'},
          {id:4, name:'typeD'}
        ]

          $scope.onChange = function(item){
            console.log("Hi world!");
            console.log(item);
            $scope.details = [
          {id:1, age:'11'},
          {id:2, age:'10'},
          {id:3, age:'9'},
          {id:4, age:'6'}
        ]
    };
  }])
```

Issues:

1) After selecting the 1st select , the value just disappears from the select box, but the value(object) is passed over to the onChange function successfully

2) Unable to populate the 2nd select box

I have created a plunkr to replicate my problem(without the webservice). Thanks!

Link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tqI0a83PiIHNUkKLj1WF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [From Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)
>
> The select directive is used together with `ngModel` to provide
>   data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including
>   setting default values).

Additionally you need to change 1st select `ng-model` as `ng-repeat` is going on `options` and `ng-model` is also same as that of `options`, should change it to `someOpetion`

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="someOpetion" ng-options="option.name for option in options" ng-change="onChange(options)">
    <option>--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <div class="input-label">
    Select Age:
  </div>
  <select ng-options="detail.age for detail in details" ng-model="someDetails">
    <option>--</option>
</select>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/v89JURPqf1mBEagzPIDo?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

use this  code: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnk289gegeLg7uXO1Duz?p=preview)

```
  <div class="input-label">
    Select Kittens:
  </div>
  <select ng-model="name" ng-options="option.name for option in options" ng-change="onChange(name)">
    <option>--</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <div class="input-label">
    Select Age:
  </div>
  <select ng-model ="age" ng-options="detail.age for detail in details">
    <option>--</option>
  </select>
```

The name of your first `ng-model = "options"` but inside controller you also use `$scope.options` as an array of object.

Moreover, In second `<select>` there is no `ng-model`. But `ng-options` needs `ng-model`.

Comment: same as that of mine :D

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem.

Here is the fixed version of your plunker

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sD0MrRJhwJtTWwC2YrIV?p=preview)

You need to add two `scope` variable in your controller to use these as your `ng-model`.

The issue for your second select was **it has no `ng-model` attribute**. Select must have `ng-model` attribute.